# How to find specific elements in a list and combine them into a new list (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, primes

First of all, I'm new to this site and to programming so if my level of writing code is bad or the way I ask my question is wrong, please point me into the right direction.

I've written a program in Python3 which enables me to get a list of all primes numbers less of equal than a given number N of my choosing. If my input is 10 for instance, my programm will give the following result:

```
>>>primes(10)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Now I'm trying to write a follow-up programm which gives me number of twinprimes for a given number N. So for instance: if N = 10, I know there are two twinprimes [3,5] and [5,7].
I tried the following:

```
def twinprimes(n):
    x = primes(n)
    ps = [] 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]+2==x[i]:
        ps.append((x[i])
    return ps
```

So I'm trying to make a new list `ps` in which all the first values of the twinprime pair are added so that I can find `len(ps)` to find the total value of twinprimes.

Now I know there is a lot wrong with my code. I just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Think about the following expression: `x[i]+2==x[i]`. This can't be true for *any* given number. `5 + 2` is never going to be equal to `5`. Perhaps you wanted to test that against another number in `x`? Twinprimes are always going to be adjacent, for example.

Comment: besides the answer given below: the `ps.append((x[i])` has one too many `(` and should be indented under the `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to test if a prime number is equal to itself plus 2:

```
if x[i]+2==x[i]:
```

No number can ever be equal to itself plus a non-zero other number, so that test is never going to pass.

You want to test if the current prime number is 2 less than the **next** number in your list:

```
if x[i] == x[i + 1] - 2:  # two adjacent primes differ by 2
```

This will run into issues with `i + 1` not being a valid index into `x` however, because you loop up to (but not including) `len(x)`; `len(x) + 1` is going to rais an `IndexError`. But you don't need to test the last prime number anyway, so the following would work:

```
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
    if x[i]  == x[i + 1] - 2:
        ps.append((x[i], x[i + 1]))
```

This adds both primes.

There are more pythonic ways of producing this list; pairing up the prime numbers with `zip()` for example, and using a list comprehension:

```
def twinprimes(n):
    x = primes(n)
    return [(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, x[1:]) if a == b - 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like the simplicity of the last option. However, your first suggestion yielded an error (expected an indented block) for me.

Comment: @Whizkid95: then make sure you have correctly indented your code. Make sure you are not accidentally mixing tabs and spaces (Python expands tabs to every 8th position, using only spaces would avoid confusion and weird errors).